# i want to AnimateWindow() in pywin32 module

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32gui

I want to do what the following code does in Python
using a certain function AnimateWindow() (from Api Windows functions)

```
var
   hWind: HWND;

begin
   Label1.Caption := 'function: AnimateWindow';
   Label1.Font.Size := 15;

   hWind := Form1.Handle;
   If (AnimateWindow(hWind, 1500, AW_HIDE) = True) Then
       Edit1.Text := 'Done'
   Else
   Begin
       Edit1.Text := 'ERROR';
       Edit2.Text := IntToStr(GetLastError());
   End;
end;
```

I tried the following code which didn't work

```
import win32gui


hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Untitled - Notepad")
win32gui.AnimateWindow(hwnd, 1500,0x00010000, True)
bbox = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
```

Comment: *didn't work* is not enough. Did you get an error message? Then report it, and the traceback. Did you get unexpected behaviour? Then say what it was and what you did expect. Please [edit] your question to follow these standard guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. **This is not a [[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (doesn't contain expected and actual outputs), so people have to guess what the problem is**
2. [[ME.TimGolden]: win32gui.AnimateWindow](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__AnimateWindow_meth.html) (part of [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)) **only takes 3 arguments, but you're passing 4**
3. According to (wrapped) [[MS.Learn]: AnimateWindow function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow) (**emphasis** is mine):

   > `[in] hWnd`
   >
   > Type: *HWND*
   >
   > A handle to the window to animate. **The calling thread must own this window**.

   So, this can be done on windows that are owned by your (thread or) by your process (as opposed to other functions (like *ShowWindow*) that work with any windows (if user has enough privileges)).

   I'm sure that your *Notepad* windows doesn't meet the criteria, at it was most likely started independently from your script.

I prepared a small example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import traceback as tb

import pywintypes as pwts
import win32api as wapi
import win32con as wcon
import win32gui as wgui


def main(*argv):
    if argv:  # Pass (at least) an argument when launching the script
        print("Create window")
        title = "Dummy Title"
        res = wgui.CreateWindow("SysListView32", title, 0, 1500, 700, 160, 90, None, None, None, None)
        print("CreateWindow returned {:}".format(res))
    else:
        title = "Untitled - Notepad"
    hwnd = wgui.FindWindow(None, title)
    if not hwnd:
        print("No window found")
        return -1
    print("Window {:} (title: {:s}) original rect: {:}".format(hwnd, title, wgui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)))
    flags = wcon.AW_CENTER
    print("Start animation")
    try:
        wgui.AnimateWindow(hwnd, 1500, flags)
    except pwts.error as e:
        tb.print_exc()
        return -1
    print("Animation done")
    print("Window final rect: {:}".format(wgui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)))
    input("Press <Enter> to exit... ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q074968476]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Window 2623562 (title: Untitled - Notepad) original rect: (146, 161, 1834, 920)
> Start animation
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q074968476\code00.py", line 28, in main
>     wgui.AnimateWindow(hwnd, 1500, flags)
> pywintypes.error: (0, 'AnimateWindow', 'No error message is available')
>
> Done.
>
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q074968476]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py 1
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Create window
> CreateWindow returned 1183484
> Window 1183484 (title: Dummy Title) original rect: (1500, 700, 1660, 790)
> Start animation
> Animation done
> Window final rect: (1500, 700, 1660, 790)
> Press <Enter> to exit...
>
> Done.
> ```

And a screenshot took during the 2<sup>nd</sup> run, while the window is expanding ("growing"):

[image: Img0]

Comment: I (thought I) explained it clear enough (my answer contains that error too): it's not your window so you can't animate it.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for reply

my output:

```
 Window 1312618 (title: Untitled - Notepad) original rect: (395, 182, 1019, 726)
Start animation

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\222.py", line 28, in main
    wgui.AnimateWindow(hwnd, 1500, flags)
pywintypes.error: (0, 'AnimateWindow', 'No error message is available')

Done.
```

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: This is not an answer, please delete it.