# ctypes function definition with paramflags and output parameters - how to retrieve the original return value of the function?

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

The python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for ctypes show an example of using the prototype definition and paramflags with the windows function GetWindowRect.

Since GetWindowRect has signature

```
BOOL GetWindowRect(
  [in]  HWND   hWnd,
  [out] LPRECT lpRect
);
```

we see that there is an **input** parameter hWnd, an **output** parameter lpRect, as well as a **return value** of the function as BOOL.

The documentation provides this snippet

```
from ctypes import POINTER, WINFUNCTYPE, windll, WinError
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND, RECT
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, POINTER(RECT))
paramflags = (1, "hwnd"), (2, "lprect")
GetWindowRect = prototype(("GetWindowRect", windll.user32), paramflags)
```

to get an usable function with input hWnd and output lpRect. Quoting from the doc:

> Functions with output parameters will automatically return the output parameter value if there is a single one, or a tuple containing the output parameter values when there are more than one, so the GetWindowRect function now returns a RECT instance, when called.

This is all well and good, but how do I get the original return value of the function (in this case a BOOL)? It seems to get lost with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Further below in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes) there is "Output parameters can be combined with the [errcheck](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck) protocol...".

You can define a function which receives the original result and can react e.g. with an exception.

The docs seem inaccurate here. If

```
errcheck(result, func, arguments)
```

(function name `errcheck` can be changed arbitrarily)

returns `arguments`, the normal processing with possible replacement by output arguments takes place. If something else is returned, it is also returned by the foreign function call.

See code comment at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3faf8e586d36e73faba13d9b61663afed6a24cb4/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L4186

Comment: I filed an [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/112423) at Python's issue tracker regarding the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Function prototypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes):

> Output parameters can be combined with the [errcheck](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck) protocol to do further output processing and error checking. The win32 `GetWindowRect` api function returns a `BOOL` to signal success or failure, so this function could do the error checking, and raises an exception when the api call failed:

I enhanced the code a bit.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
from ctypes import wintypes as wts
import sys


GetWindowRectProto = cts.WINFUNCTYPE(wts.BOOL, wts.HWND, cts.POINTER(wts.RECT))
GetWindowRectParamFlags = (1, "hwnd"), (2, "lprect")
GetWindowRect = GetWindowRectProto(("GetWindowRect", cts.windll.user32), GetWindowRectParamFlags)
GetLastErrorProto = cts.WINFUNCTYPE(wts.DWORD)
GetLastError = GetLastErrorProto(("GetLastError", cts.windll.kernel32), ())


def error_checker(result, func, args):
    #print(result, func, args)
    if not result:
        print(f"{func} call failed: {GetLastError()}")
    return result, args[-1]


def main(*argv):
    use_errcheck = len(argv) > 0
    if use_errcheck:
        print("Using ErrCheck")
        GetWindowRect.errcheck = error_checker
    else:
        print("NOT using ErrCheck")
    wnd = 0
    print(f"Calling GetWindowRect({wnd})...")
    res = GetWindowRect(wnd)
    print("Called")
    print(res)
    if use_errcheck:
        rect = res[-1]
    else:
        rect = res
    print(rect.top, rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.right)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

This is one example of using *ErrCheck* (I'm returning the original return code and the output argument), you can do whatever you want in that function (including raising exceptions).
In my case, I passed ***0*** as window handle (some functions treat that as the desktop (root) window), which *GetWindowRect* doesn't like, hence the error (and uninitialized rectangle). I didn't get a valid handle as I didn't want to also "import" other *WinAPI* functions that I mentioned (*GetDesktopWindow*, *GetTopWindow*, ...).

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q077551174]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> NOT using ErrCheck
> Calling GetWindowRect(0)...
> Called
> <ctypes.wintypes.RECT object at 0x0000019622657740>
> 0 0 0 0
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\python.exe" ./code00.py dummyarg
> Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Using ErrCheck
> Calling GetWindowRect(0)...
> <WinFunctionType object at 0x000001D14E2A64D0> call failed: 1400
> Called
> (0, <ctypes.wintypes.RECT object at 0x000001D14DEC7740>)
> 0 0 0 0
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen, (if set) the error checker is called as part of the foreign function call (and its returned value becomes the foreign function's one).

This is one way of achieving your goal. There are more:

1. Going the old fashioned way (specifying *ArgTypes* and *ResType*) and calling the function just like one would do from *C*. I want to mention here [[SO]: How to use ctypes' errcheck? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50675541/4788546) (which this question **seems to be a duplicate** of). On this subject, [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) might also be interesting
2. Using [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) which is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s (much friendlier, as it contains a lot of boilerplate code). Documentation (*WiP*) can be found at [[GitHub.MHammond]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32) (or [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)). An example: [[SO]: i want to AnimateWindow() in pywin32 module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75006792/4788546)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - there are some cases where one may not want to use the error checking mechanism to retrieve the output of the called c-procedure, especially if it uses a different mechanism to signal an error than the return value. I provided an alternative way of getting the result in an aswer.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I never use the “prototype with *paramflags*” syntax. There is less control over the final result as you've found.  Here's my implementation using `.argtypes`, `.restype`, and `.errcheck` using a generic `boolcheck` error handler common to many Win32 functions:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

# Reusable base class for structures to print themselves.
class Repr(ct.Structure):
    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'{self.__class__.__name__}(' +
                ', '.join([f'{n}={getattr(self, n)}'
                           for n, _ in self._fields_]) + ')')

# My version of RECT that can print itself
class RECT(w.RECT, Repr):
    pass

# Error checking for Win32 functions that return BOOL
# and support GetLastError() on failure.
def boolcheck(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ct.WinError(ct.get_last_error())
    return None

# Ensure capturing the last error code directly after the function call
user32 = ct.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

GetForegroundWindow = user32.GetForegroundWindow
GetForegroundWindow.argtypes = ()
GetForegroundWindow.restype = w.HWND

_GetWindowRect = user32.GetWindowRect
_GetWindowRect.argtypes = w.HWND, ct.POINTER(RECT)
_GetWindowRect.restype = w.BOOL
_GetWindowRect.errcheck = boolcheck
# My preference instead of using prototype()...more control using a wrapper
def GetWindowRect(hwnd):
    r = RECT()
    _GetWindowRect(hwnd, ct.byref(r))  # will now throw exception on failure
    return r

print(GetWindowRect(GetForegroundWindow()))
GetWindowRect(None)
```

Output:

```
RECT(left=2561, top=400, right=3461, bottom=1437)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 40, in <module>
    GetWindowRect(None)
  File "C:\test.py", line 36, in GetWindowRect
    _GetWindowRect(hwnd, ct.byref(r))
  File "C:\test.py", line 19, in boolcheck
    raise ct.WinError(ct.get_last_error())
OSError: [WinError 1400] Invalid window handle.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers mention handling the return value as part of the error checking procedure, I would like to post an answer that works even if you do not define an error checking procedure.

As mentioned in the answer by CristiFati, we can feed 0 as the window handle.

If we do not care about the original return value of the function, and we do not set up an errcheck procedure, the code looks like variant 1 below. We can however define a pointer to the rect structure an input, and this will be filled by the function while preserving the return value of the function (variant 2 below).

```
from ctypes import POINTER, WINFUNCTYPE, windll, byref
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND, RECT


# variant 1 - lose return value
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, POINTER(RECT))
paramflags = (1, "hwnd"), (2, "lprect")
GetWindowRect = prototype(("GetWindowRect", windll.user32), paramflags)

rect = GetWindowRect(0)
print(f"TOP: {rect.top}, LEFT:{rect.left}, BOTTOM:{rect.bottom}, RIGHT:{rect.right}")
# prints TOP: 0, LEFT:0, BOTTOM:0, RIGHT:0

# variant 2 - keep return value and pass a pointer to the output RECT structure
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, POINTER(RECT))
paramflags = (1, "hwnd"), (1, "lprect")  # note that lpret has type 1 here instead of 2
GetWindowRect = prototype(("GetWindowRect", windll.user32), paramflags)

rect = RECT()
return_value = GetWindowRect(0, byref(rect))
print(f"OUTPUT: {return_value} TOP: {rect.top}, LEFT:{rect.left}, BOTTOM:{rect.bottom}, RIGHT:{rect.right}")
# prints OUTPUT: 0 TOP: 0, LEFT:0, BOTTOM:0, RIGHT:0
```

This is more generally useful if the return value is not directly related to the error state of the called c-procedure.

Comment: FYI: In my answer, call `_GetWindowRect` directly without the wrapper will get you the return value if you don't set the `.errcheck` parameter.